# Center of mass in n dimension, possible?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to calculate the center of mass for some 20-dimension ($x_i, i=1,\ldots,20$) particles? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: "Particles" in 20 dimensions ? Are you sure ?

Answer (score 3):

*Definition: The center of mass is a **position** defined relative to an object or system of objects. It is the **average position** of all the parts of the system, **weighted according to their masses**. For simple rigid objects with uniform density, the center of mass is located at the centroid.*

Yes (I think?), because the centre of mass is a position (a point) with components $x$, $y$, $z$, etc. It can be represented in $n$-dimentional space as you can always add another component. To calcluate it however would be a bit different. The weighted average position of the object would be found using calculus - I would have a look at [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~conroy/m126-general/centerOfMass/centerOfMass01.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Econroy/m126-general/centerOfMass/centerOfMass01.pdf). and then generalise it to higher dimentions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Suppose you have a system of particles with positions $\mathbf{r}_1,...,\mathbf{r}_n$ with masses $m_1,...,m_n$. The center of mass then is
$$\mathbf{r}_{\text{C.O.M}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i\mathbf{r}_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i}$$
Assuming all the position vectors are expressed in the standard basis, this works in however many dimensions you please.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I calculate ri for each dimension?

Comment: If you're working in $N$ dimensions, then $\mathbf{r}=(x_1,...,x_N)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$.

Comment: Thanks for you comment sir, but what is ei?

Comment: The $i$th unit vector in the standard basis.

Comment: Thanks, but I have problem with "e" your regarded equation. I

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis

Comment: Thanks. I thing that's so difficult to implement ei in 20 dimensions