# How to Calculate center of mass for 20 dimensions particles

Tags: geometry, physics

I have a problem with calculation the center of mass of 20-dimension particles,
some thing like this:

A = [1 6 8 54 6 8 5 4 8 9 6 4 7 9 6 6 3 8 43 9] , Mass = 0.25

B = [2 6 3 4 6 8 4 4 8 5 6 4 2 2 6 6 3 8 1 1] , Mass = 0.6

C = [4 3 4 53 6 2 5 21 8 1 6 2 37 2 6 2 3 1 43 9] , Mass = 0.05

Could anyone guide me to find the solution for center of mass in each dimension (x1, x2, ... x20)?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Microelec I already answered this question a few days ago. Use the solution I provided there. I'm flagging this question to mods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center of mass in n dimension, possible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742558/center-of-mass-in-n-dimension-possible)

Comment: Tnx guys, but I think in that question, I haven't find clear answer because I didn't use some examples to clarify my purpose to visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center of mass is simply a weighted average. That is, we will have
$$
P_{\text{center}} = \frac{0.25 A + 0.6 B + 0.05 C}{0.25 + 0.6 + 0.05}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, Can I use above equation for each dimension? Can you explain more about A,B or C. for example is it true? Px1 = (0.25*A(x1) + 0.6*B(x1) + 0.05*C(x1))/0.25+0.6+0.05

Comment: Yes, applying the equation to each entry individually is the same as applying the operation to the vectors $A,B,C$.

Comment: Thanks, But how can I provide A,B,C vectors from my initial Particles?

Comment: The entries of the vector $A$ are the coordinates of the point $A$

Comment: Thanks, If I assimilate completely, The center of mass on the first dimension ($x_1$) is : $P_{center} (x_1) = \frac{(0.25 * 1 + 0.6*2 + 0.05*4)}{(0.25+0.6+0.05)} = 1.2 $ ,is it true?

Comment: That should be $4 \cdot 0.05$ instead, but otherwise correct

Comment: Excuse me sir, How you calculate that? that different with my one, is the above equation true?

Comment: @Microelec Your updated equation for the first coordinate is correct

Comment: Thanks sir @Omnomnomnom, I greatly appreciate your consideration and time you have got for me

Comment: @Microelec Glad to help. If you are satisfied with this answer, please "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ($\color{green}{\checkmark}$) on its left.